# CSS - My bootstrap columns aren't breaking correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list which looks like this:

https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/QgbQvv

but somehow the columns aren't breaking correctly when resizing the window. I want to keep it readable when someone access my page with a smartphone or other small devices.

Any help would be appreciate

(reduced code)

HTML

```
<ol class="product-list">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <li>
      <div class="row vertical-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-right">
          <strong>Productname</strong>
          <span class="product-description">
            Some text, which describes the product lorem ipsum.
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-holder col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
        </div>
        <div class="circle col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <span class="circle-number"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="row vertical-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-right">
          <strong>Productname</strong>
          <span class="product-description">
            Some text, which describes the product lorem ipsum.
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-holder col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
        </div>
        <div class="circle col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <span class="circle-number"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 large-image-holder">
      <img class="image-large" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <li>
      <div class="row vertical-center">
        <div class="circle col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <span class="circle-number"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-holder col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
          <strong>Productname</strong>
          <span class="product-description">
            Some text, which describes the product lorem ipsum.
          </span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>
     <li>
      <div class="row vertical-center">
        <div class="circle col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <span class="circle-number"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-holder col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
          <strong>Productname</strong>
          <span class="product-description">
            Some text, which describes the product lorem ipsum.
          </span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
counter-reset: counter;
}
.circle-number {
  counter-increment: counter;
}
.circle-number:after {
  content: counter(counter);
}

.product-list{
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.product-description{
  display: block;

}

img{
  margin-top: 15px;  
}

li{

  /*display: inline-block;*/
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #47c9e5;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;


}

.large-image-holder{
  text-align: center;
  object-fit: cover;

}

.image-large{
   object-fit: cover;
   width: 100%;
}

.circle{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #47c9e5;
  max-width: 70px;
  max-height: 70px;
}

.circle-number{
  font-size: 45px;
  color: white;
}

.vertical-center{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-holder{
  text-align: center;
}

li:last-child{
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific, from that Codepen it seems the bootstrap columns are collapsing properly. Also, your HTML is invalid as you can't have div directly inside ol or ul.

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna remove the ol and li elements later. Just wanted to avoid divitis. What I mean is that the elements, such as the producttext, picture and the circle are overlapping each other. But I want them to break when tthere is not enough space.